# Referenced tables aren't opening even though I coded them

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

My referenced tables aren't opening even though I have coded them. I am in the correct database and I have created the tables I need. I ran the show tables command and only two of my tables show up. I have also checked that I am using the correct database, I still can't find out how to make my tables show up.

Here is my code for reference:

```
BEGIN;
/* Create Employees table */
CREATE TABLE Employees (
EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY,
EmployeeName VARCHAR(50),
EmployeeDateOfHire DATE,
EmployeeAddress VARCHAR(100),
EmployeePhone VARCHAR(15),
ClassAssignment VARCHAR(50)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/* Create Attendance table /
CREATE TABLE Attendance (
Attendance_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Attendance_Date DATE,
Attendance_Status VARCHAR(10),
Student_ID INT,
FOREIGN KEY (Student_ID) REFERENCES Students(STUDENT_ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
/ Create Tuition table */

CREATE TABLE Tuition (
TuitionID INT PRIMARY KEY,
StudentID INT,
InvoiceDate DATE,
Amount DECIMAL(10, 2),
Pmt_Status VARCHAR(20),
PaidAmount DECIMAL(10, 2),
FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Students(Student_ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/* Enroll_Checklist table */
CREATE TABLE Enroll_Checklist (
Enroll_Checklist_ID INT,
Student_info_sheet VARCHAR(45),
Student_medical_sheet VARCHAR(45),
Authorized_pickup_sheet VARCHAR(45),
Student_birth_certificate VARCHAR(45),
Social_security_card CHAR(12),
Immunization_record VARCHAR(45),
Registration_fee DECIMAL(10, 2),
Student_ID INT,
Employee_ID INT
);

/* Create Authorized_pickup table */

CREATE TABLE Authorized_pickup (
Authorized_pickup_ID INT,
Authorized_pickup_1 VARCHAR(45),
Authorized_pickup_2 VARCHAR(45),
Authorized_pickup_3 VARCHAR(45),
STUDENT_ID INT
);

/* CREATE PARENT_GUARDIAN TABLE*/

CREATE TABLE PARENT_GUARDIAN(
PG_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
PG_FNAME VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
PG_LNAME VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
PG_PHONE_NUM CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
PG_ADDRESS VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PG_CITY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PG_STATE CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
PG_ZIPCode CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PG_RELATIONSHIP_STUDENT VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL
);

/* CREATE CLASS TABLE*/
CREATE TABLE CLASS (
CLASS_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Class_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Age_Group INT NOT NULL,
Room_Num INT NOT NULL,
Room_ID INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(Room_ID) REFERENCES Classroom(Room_ID)
);

/* CREATE CLASSROOM TABLE*/

CREATE TABLE Classroom (
Room_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Room_Type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Capacity INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
STUDENT_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
STUDENT_FNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_LNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_DOB DATE NOT NULL,
STUDENT_ADDRESS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_CITY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_STATE CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_ZIPCode CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_START_DATE DATE,
STUDENT_PHONE_NUM CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_ALLERGIES VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_TUITION_RATE DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
CLASS_ID INT,
FOREIGN KEY(CLASS_ID) REFERENCES CLASS(CLASS_ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/* CREATE RELATIONSHIP TABLE*/
CREATE TABLE RELATIONSHIP (
RELATIONSHIP_ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
STUDENT
```

I have tried specifying the engine, I have tried running each table code separately, and I have tried to show each table separately but I still keep getting the error message 1824: failed to open the referenced table. I am quite new to mysql and I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Which line is getting that error?

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Students(Student_ID)` There's no `Students` table. There's a `STUDENT` table, but it's defined later, the referenced table has to be defined first.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY(Room_ID) REFERENCES Classroom(Room_ID)` The `Classroom` table is defined after this.

Comment: So fix 2 problems: Get the table names right, and fix the order so the referenced table is first.

Comment: You can also leave the foreign keys out of the table definitions. Then add them all at the end with `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: @Barmar Reordering the tables worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the issue:

In this table **Tuition** you used a foreign key of **Students** table. But while creating the table there is not **Students** table present at that moment. So to run this you have to set the parameter ***SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;*** at the top of the query to stop MySQL to check the Foreign key.

Here is a sample:

```
/* Stoping MySql to check foreign key */
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

/* Create Employees table */
CREATE TABLE Employees (
EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY,
EmployeeName VARCHAR(50),
EmployeeDateOfHire DATE,
EmployeeAddress VARCHAR(100),
EmployeePhone VARCHAR(15),
ClassAssignment VARCHAR(50)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/* Create Attendance table /
CREATE TABLE Attendance (
Attendance_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Attendance_Date DATE,
Attendance_Status VARCHAR(10),
Student_ID INT,
FOREIGN KEY (Student_ID) REFERENCES Students(STUDENT_ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
/ Create Tuition table */

CREATE TABLE Tuition (
TuitionID INT PRIMARY KEY,
StudentID INT,
InvoiceDate DATE,
Amount DECIMAL(10, 2),
Pmt_Status VARCHAR(20),
PaidAmount DECIMAL(10, 2),
FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Students(Student_ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/* Enroll_Checklist table */
CREATE TABLE Enroll_Checklist (
Enroll_Checklist_ID INT,
Student_info_sheet VARCHAR(45),
Student_medical_sheet VARCHAR(45),
Authorized_pickup_sheet VARCHAR(45),
Student_birth_certificate VARCHAR(45),
Social_security_card CHAR(12),
Immunization_record VARCHAR(45),
Registration_fee DECIMAL(10, 2),
Student_ID INT,
Employee_ID INT
);

/* Create Authorized_pickup table */

CREATE TABLE Authorized_pickup (
Authorized_pickup_ID INT,
Authorized_pickup_1 VARCHAR(45),
Authorized_pickup_2 VARCHAR(45),
Authorized_pickup_3 VARCHAR(45),
STUDENT_ID INT
);

/* CREATE PARENT_GUARDIAN TABLE*/

CREATE TABLE PARENT_GUARDIAN(
PG_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
PG_FNAME VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
PG_LNAME VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
PG_PHONE_NUM CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
PG_ADDRESS VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PG_CITY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PG_STATE CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
PG_ZIPCode CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PG_RELATIONSHIP_STUDENT VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL
);

/* CREATE CLASS TABLE*/
CREATE TABLE CLASS (
CLASS_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Class_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Age_Group INT NOT NULL,
Room_Num INT NOT NULL,
Room_ID INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(Room_ID) REFERENCES Classroom(Room_ID)
);

/* CREATE CLASSROOM TABLE*/

CREATE TABLE Classroom (
Room_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Room_Type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Capacity INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
STUDENT_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
STUDENT_FNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_LNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_DOB DATE NOT NULL,
STUDENT_ADDRESS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_CITY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_STATE CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_ZIPCode CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_START_DATE DATE,
STUDENT_PHONE_NUM CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_ALLERGIES VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
STUDENT_TUITION_RATE DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
CLASS_ID INT,
FOREIGN KEY(CLASS_ID) REFERENCES CLASS(CLASS_ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/* Enabling MySql to check foreign key again */
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```